# variable accessibility problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, class, global-variables, nsinteger

I have two class ..

in one of them I am using six buttons with their tag..

like this

```
[btnF1 setTag:1];
```

and I am using this tag

like this..

```
- (void)showPhoto:(UIButton*)btnSender       {    
    NSLog(@"showPhoto:%d",btnSender.tag);   
}
```

Now I want to make variable that stores the value of `btnSender.tag` and I can also use that value in any other class also...

I made two approches..
1) I made a variable in this class which stores btnSender.tag value and I tried to use this value in other class but it is giving me null

2) I tried out the global variable but not able to see the value of the global variable in the NSLog..

I am not using IB

Help me out...:)

Comment: Your method 1) I made a variable in this class which stores btnSender.tag value and I tried to use this value in other class should work. Can you post some code?

Comment: @7KV7..well I have defined it in .h file as a NSInteger..and then set the getter and setter method in that class then ...i put the btnsender.tag's value in that

Comment: just set it as int. That will be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults or UILabel to store the value of button tag. But for using UILabel you will have to Outlet it to a hidden label in your XIB only then it will retain its value.

NSUserDefaults stores the value permanently till you refresh it. So there won't be a problem of retaining the values.

So better approach is to use `NSUserDefaults` as shown below. May be you can put this on an event (for Example ButtonClick if you are going to next view on a button click.)

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
[userDef setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",btnSender.tag] forKey:@"BtnTag"];
```

Now when you go to next view, you can access it using below code:

```
int tagValue = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] valueForKey:@"BtnTag"] intValue];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @parth..it is giving me this warning...'NSUserDefaults' may not respond to '+standardDefaults'

Comment: +1 for doing your best to answer a poorly written question, but -1 for the whole UILabel thing. Using a hidden label to facilitate communication between two objects? NSUserDefaults seems better by comparison, but it would be better to just get the two objects to talk to each other.

Comment: @rathodrc: oops!! it is `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];` sorry it was a typing mistake!! Just make `standardUserDefaults` in place of `standardDefaults`. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @rathodrc: Check it and tell me if it worked for you? I am sure it will. :-)

Comment: @parth..since I am a new bie ..i want to ask you...what is this BtnTag??

Comment: @rathodrc: `BtnTag` is just an identifier or key for the value where your `btnSender.tag` value is saved.

Comment: @parth ...it is crashing...when I using this..... int tagValue = [[[NSUserDefaults alloc] valueForKey:@"BtnTag"] intValue];...and printing the value of int tagValue..it is crashing...

Comment: @rathodrc: In NSLog what do u write? can you please post that code here?

Comment: @rathodrc: Try this `NSLog(@"%d",tagValue);` It was crashing in your case as you are trying to print an integer using %@ specifier. %@ is specifier for strings and not integers. So this would work: `NSLog(@"%d",tagValue);`

Comment: @Parth...it is working...!!! how dumb I am...Thanks bhai(considering u r a gujarati ...:))

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface urViewController : UIViewController 

{
 int buttonTag;
}
@property int buttonTag;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only one object that should be responsible for dealing directly with the objects (buttons and anything else) in your view, and that's the view controller. If some other object wants to change the label on a button, disable a button, or otherwise modify a button, it should do so by talking to the view controller. That might seem a roundabout way to do things when you can just access the button directly, but...

- It completely solves your problem with sharing tags. Nobody but the view controller needs to care about tags.
- Concentrating responsibility for everything in the view makes your code less buggy and much more maintainable.